# Redbean R::Find returns empty beans

Tags: php, database, redbean

using this:

```
    $rdy  = R::find( 'players','room=0');
    $count = count($rdy);
    if($count>1)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
        {
            $id = $rdy[$i]->id;
            $user = R::load('players',$id);
            if($user->id!=0)
            {

            //changing $user variables..

            R::store($user);
            }
        }
    }
```

but beans that R::find() function found give empty fields,
am i using it wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your database has values that match your search?

Comment: yes, and its finding beans but for example if I try " echo $rdy[0]->id " it will give empty field

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first line

```
    $rdy  = R::find( 'players','room=0');
```

with

```
   $rdy = R::find('players', " room = ?", [0]);
```

You can place variables instead of the hard coded 0.

You can also check on multiple properties and pass multiple variables in the array